# Generate a sequence of all cases

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators, integer-sequence

There is a sequence of numbers that satisfies
$a_1=2$, $a_n-a_{n-1}\in \{1,3,5\}$
[image]
I tried to enumerate all possibilities using the code below

```
n = 3;
NestList[Join @@ Outer[Plus, #, {1, 3, 5}] &, {{2}}, n - 1]
```

> {{{2}}, {{3, 5, 7}}, {{4, 6, 8}, {6, 8, 10}, {8, 10, 12}}}

Now I hope to get such a list, is there an easy way?

> {{2,3,4},{2,3,6},{2,3,8},{2,5,6},{2,5,8},{2,5,10},{2,7,8},{2,7,10},{2,7,12}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Accumulate /@ Prepend[2] /@ Tuples[{1, 3, 5}, 2]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 8}, {2, 5, 10}, > 
>   {2, 7, 8}, {2, 7, 10}, {2, 7, 12}}
> ```

And, for fun:

```
ng = NestGraph[{1, 3, 5} + # &, 2, 2, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
root = 2;
sinks = VertexList[ng, _?(VertexOutDegree[ng, #] == 0 &)];

Join @@ (FindPath[ng, ##, Infinity, All] & @@@ Thread[{root, sinks}])
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 7, 8}, {2, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 8}, 
>  {2, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 10}, {2, 7, 12}}
> ```

Comment: Can we generate such a graph? https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8mKd.png `NestGraph[{1,3,5}+#&,2,3,VertexLabels->Automatic]` It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @expression, I can't think of a simple way to get the graph in the link. You might want to post it as a new question with a brief explanation of the context.

Answer (score 2):

```
FoldList[Plus, 2, #] & /@ Tuples[{1, 3, 5}, 2]
```